# how to create a matrix of coordinates and how to calculate the distance b/w coordinates

Tags: matlab

I want to create a matrix as given below for any input, and suppose the input is `"4"`.

```
a1 =  (-10.0)   (0,0)   (10,0)   (20,0)
     (-10,5)   (0,5)   (10,5)   (20,5)
     (-10,10)  (0,10)  (10,10)  (20,10)
     (-10,15)  (0,15)  (10,15)  (20,15)
```

But I don't know how to do and also I want to calculate the distance of a single element say (0,0) w.r. t the rest of the elements?

**EDIT:**

The position of the origin `(0,0)` can change like this:

```
a2= (-20.0)   (-10,0)   (0,0)   (10,0)
     (-20,5)   (-10,5)   (0,5)   (10,5)
     (-20,10)  (-10,10)  (0,10)  (10,10)
     (-20,15)  (-10,15)  (0,15)  (10,15)
```

the next matrix will be

```
a3= (-30.0)   (-20,0)   (10,0)   (0,0)
     (-30,5)   (-20,5)   (10,5)   (0,5)
     (-30,10)  (-20,10)  (10,10)  (0,10)
     (-30,15)  (-20,15)  (10,15)  (0,15)
```

and

```
a4= (0,-5)  (10,-5)  (20,-5)  (30,-5)
     (0,0)   (10,0)   (20,0)   (30,0)
     (0,5)   (10,5)   (20,5)   (30,5)
     (0,10)  (10,10)  (20,10)  (30,10)
```

and then

```
a5= (-10,-5)  (0,-5)  (10,-5)  (20,-5)
     (-10,0)   (0,0)   (10,0)   (20,0)
     (-10,5)   (0,5)   (10,5)   (20,5)
     (-10,10)  (0,10)  (10,10)  (20,10)
```

and a6, a7, so on..... i will have to perform the same for all the elements by changing the position of the element `(0,0)` as mentioned above.

Comment: Is `(-15, 10)` correct or do you mean `(-10, 15)`? Could you post the rule how to calculate the single elements?

What have you tried so far?

Comment: sorry, yes actually it is (-10, 15).

Comment: @user123 Will the step size (10 in horizontal direction, 5 in vertical direction) always be the same?

Comment: @user123 I changed my answer according to your edit. Let me know if this is what you where looking for.

Comment: Thanks a lot...i had tried it as you mentioned above.but it is still showing the error

Comment: yes.. in this case, the distance (horizontal 10 and vertical 5)  will remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

To generate your array depending on the size `n`, the x and y position of the origin `(0,0)` and the x and y stepsize you can use a function like this:

```
function a = generate_array(n,x0_pos,y0_pos,x_step,y_step)

    a1 = linspace(0 - (x0_pos - 1) * x_step, (n - x0_pos) * x_step, n);
    a2 = linspace(0 - (y0_pos - 1) * y_step, (n - y0_pos) * y_step, n);

    for i = 1:n
        for j= 1:n
            a{i,j} = [a1(i), a2(j)];
        end
    end

end
```

Please note that since you are using an older Matlab version this function needs to be in seperate file named `generate_array.m`.

Now you need a function to calculate the [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) from an arbitrary point to all points in the one of these cell arrays. This function could for example look like this:

```
function dist = calc_distance(arr,x,y)
    n = size(arr,1);
    for i = 1:n
        for j= 1:n
            dist{i,j} = norm(arr{i,j} - [x, y]);
        end
    end
end
```

Again make sure to save this function in a seperate file named `calc_distance.m`.

In your main script you could use the two function like this to generate the arrays in your example and calculate the distances:

```
n = 4;
x_step = 10;
y_step = 5;

x_point = -10;
y_point = 5;

for j = 1:n
    y0_pos = j;
    for i = 1:n
        x0_pos = i;
        a_parent{i,j} = generate_array(n, x0_pos, y0_pos, x_step, y_step);
        dist_parent{i,j} = calc_distance(a_parent{i,j},x_point,y_point);
    end
end
```

This will construct a 4x4 cell array `a_parent` where each cell contains another 4x4 cell array. In the `(1,1)` cell will be the cell array of coordinates where the origin is at the position `(1,1)`, in the `(1,2)` cell will be the cell array of coordinates where the origin is at `(1,2)` and so forth.

Additionally it will generate a cell array called `dist_parent` which again contains 4x4 cell arrays with all the distances for the 4x4 different cell arrays to your respective point. As an example I calculated all the distances to the point `(5,5)`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But the distance calculation part is not working .It is giving an error "Function definitions are not permitted in this context.".

Comment: Also, if I will have to move the origin every time and also have to calculate the distance w.r.t the moved origin.

Comment: Hi! How did you define the function? If you define it as a local function in the same .m-file make sure that the function definition is at the end of the document. If you define it in an extra file make sure that the file name and function name are the same. What version of Matlab are you using? Function definitions inside a script are only possible for versions newer than 2016b.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your second comment correctly. Please specify exactly what you are trying to do in your question. What do you mean by moving the origin? Does this change the array `a` or do you only need to calculate the distance from another point to the same array `a`?

Comment: hey....I am using Matlab 2015b. and in my second comment the array 'a' will change every time.i.e[-20 0] [10 0]   [0 0]  [10 0]
[-20 5] [10 5]   [0 5]  [10 5]
[-20 10]    [10 10]  [0 10] [10 10]
[-20 15]    [10 15]  [0 15] [10 15] and have to do the same for all the elements

Comment: Could you edit your question and add some examples how the array changes with different inputs?